# Overriding equals method not working on using object as key in hashmap?

Tags: java, collections

I have Overridden equals method of Person class comparing the name attribute of class and if they are equal returning back true from equals method.

When i am creating the instance of Person object and using it as key in hashmap, while retrieving using a new object with same name i am not able to retrieve back the associated value from hashMap.

Below is my

```
import java.util.HashMap;
```

import java.util.Map;

public class ToStringTest {

```
public static void main(String[] args) {

    Person person = new Person("Jack", "California");
    Map<Person,String> personsMap = new HashMap<>();
    personsMap.put(person,"MyCar");
   Person otherPerson = new Person("Jack", "California");
    System.out.println(personsMap.get(otherPerson));
}
```

}

class Person {

```
String name;
String city;

public Person(String name, String city) {
    this.name = name;
    this.city = city;
}

@Override
public String toString() {
    return "Name : " + this.name + ", City : " + this.city;
}

@Override
public boolean equals(Object o) {

    Person person = (Person) o;
    if(person.name.equals(this.name)){
        return true;
    }

    return false;
}
```

}

This is printing null while retrieving from using otherPerson object.

Could someone please explain this behavior.

Comment: don't forget about `hashcode` implementation

Answer (score 0, accepted):

When you add new person in map `personsMap.put(person,"MyCar");` first of all if key is not null the position where the element will be put is determined. It is determined by calling `hashcode` method for key. There are a few steps after but it doesn't matter for this example.

Since you don't override `hashcode()` your `person` and `otherPerson` will have different `hashcode`.

The same happens when you try to get value by some key. To find position where the element is, `hashcode()` will be invoked. But `otherPerson` has different `hashcode` and it will lead to position where is no item (`null`)

`equals()` is used when at the same position there are many elements (in list or tree structure). Then to find the right item they will be compared by `equals()` method

Comment: I tried overriding hasCode method for Person class and it worked. Able to retrieve the object from map using otherPerson object.Thanks